# Best approach for returning connection objects to HikariCP pool

Tags: java, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I am trying to use HikariCP connection pool. I was able to get it to work and get a connection that I could use. I am not sure what is the best approach for returning the connection to the pool.

I have the following questions:

- Should I close the connection when I am done, rely on *idleTimeout*
  and *maxLifetime* settings or is there another call that I can use so
  as not to hog the connections from the pool?
- If I close the connections (instead of returning to the pool), would
  that not result in additional connection objects being created
  to meet the requirements of the *connection pool* size?

Looking for helpful suggestions.

Comment: Not sure about Hikari, but in most connection pools, what you get is not the actual connection, but rather a wrapper that has a different `close` method (apart from other things). Said close method actually returns the connection to the pool rather than closes it.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

As with most connection pools, Hikari doesn't give you an actual JDBC Connection when you ask for one. What it does instead is give you a proxy that implements the `Connection` interface. In the case of Hikari - it's a `ConnectionProxy` object.

This proxy serves a few purposes, the main of which is - take the control of opening/closing connections and statements away from you and into the connection pool. This happens automagically *and you should be using your connections as usual*. This includes closing them after use.

If you look at the [source code for Hikari](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP), at the `ConnectionProxy` class in particular, you will see that the `close()` method is very different from the standard one. The code reads as:

> Mark the connection as closed, do cleanup, reset underlying connection state and params.

Hence, simply calling `close()` will just clean and return the connection to the pool.

Comment: Yea I was confused about this as well but having stepped through their source-code I can confirm that simply calling .close() is all you need to do to safely return the connection to the pool.

Comment: If i close the dataSource rather closing the connection by calling shutdown() what will the impact of that?

Comment: @IrfanNasim If you close the `dataSource`, it will shutdown the entire pool, along with any active or inactive connections associated with it.

Comment: @IrfanNasim I can only concur with the comments already there - the question is trivially answerable by reading the docs. It also has little to do with either this question or my answer to it.